# my python3 code throwing a Type:Error and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a raspberry pi using the SenseHat for it. Using `get_temperature` spits out the temperature in a long float and I've been trying to change it ,but I just get a type error

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat ()

import time

red = [225, 0, 0]
green = [0, 225, 0]
blue = [0, 0, 225]

while 1 == 1:
    time.sleep(10)

    rawTemp = sense.get_temperature()
    temp = int(rawTemp * 1.8 + 22)

    if temp <= 70:
        tempColor = blue
    elif temp >= 74:
        tempColor = red
    else:
        tempColor = green

    sense.show_message(temp, text_colour = tempColor)
```

---

**And here is the error code that I get along with it**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python Projects/tempertureReader.py", line 29, in <module>
    sense.show_message(temp, text_colour = tempColor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 450, in show_message
    for s in text_string:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: it says something like, you are trying to pass `int` in the place you were supposed to pass a `string`,  i the `sense.show_message()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is asking str for

```
sense.show_message(temp, text_colour = tempColor)
```

and you giving to this function int in temp, try this:

```
sense.show_message(str(temp), text_colour = tempColor)
```